# Adding padding left on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

i've this page http://www.grisard.ch/uferstrasse/imfoyeru90/

As you can see from the screenshot in mobile ther's no padding left (but i've setted media queries and i think it's ok).

How can i solve it?[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row fluid">

                <div class="col-md-6 simona">
                   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
      <!-- Indicators -->

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"> <img src="img/simona.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="First slide">

        </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="img/simona2.jpg" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Second    slide">

        </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="img/simona3.jpg" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Third slide">

        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 logo">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.png" />  
                </div>


                 <div class="col-md-6 date">

                  <h3>AHNENGALERIE<br>Uferstrasse 90, 4057 Basel</h3>
                    <h5 class="date">27.10.2015 &#x2013 07.12.2015 </h5>   

                </div>

                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">    
            <div class="col-md-3 dates"><p><strong></b>Vernissage:</strong><br>27.10.2015<br>18.00–20.00 Uhr</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 dates"><p><strong>Lesung:</strong><br>16.11.2015<br>18.00 Uhr</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 dates"><p><strong>Finissage:</strong><br>07.12.2015<br>18.00–20.00 Uhr</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-8"> <p class="bio">Bild eins: «unsagbar» 
    aus dem Zyklus «Ahnengalerie»
    Raffaello hat sie geküsst
    Leonardo war beim Vesper 
    zugegen. Hinter dem Vorhang kommt sie auf eine neue Idee.
    Sie könnte als Skulptur leben. 
    In meiner Malerei geht es um 
    Formen von Lebenserfahrungen.
    Um die Sehnsucht, das Unsagbare darstellen zu können. Und um die Unerträglichkeit, dafür niemals erlösende Bilder zu finden. 
    Was geschieht - ich lasse mich ins Unterbewusstsein fallen und finde Fragmente.
    Künstlerin: Simona Deflorin.</p></div> 

            </div>
            </div>




    </div>
     </div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen 
              and (min-device-width: 320px) 
              and (max-device-width: 480px)
              and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
                  .dates { padding-left: 15px !important; }
                  .bio { padding-left: 15px !important; }
            }

            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width : 768px) 
            and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { 
                .dates { padding-left: 15px !important; }
                  .bio { padding-left: 15px !important; }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this, hopefully it will resolve your issue.**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row fluid">

                <div class="col-md-6 simona">
                   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
      <!-- Indicators -->

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"> <img src="img/simona.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="First slide">

        </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="img/simona2.jpg" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Second    slide">

        </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="img/simona3.jpg" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Third slide">

        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 logo">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.png" />  
                </div>


                 <div class="col-md-6 date">

                  <h3>AHNENGALERIE<br>Uferstrasse 90, 4057 Basel</h3>
                    <h5 class="date">27.10.2015 &#x2013 07.12.2015 </h5>   

                </div>

                        <div class="row container">
                        <div class="col-md-6">    
            <div class="col-md-3 dates"><p><strong></b>Vernissage:</strong><br>27.10.2015<br>18.00–20.00 Uhr</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 dates"><p><strong>Lesung:</strong><br>16.11.2015<br>18.00 Uhr</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 dates"><p><strong>Finissage:</strong><br>07.12.2015<br>18.00–20.00 Uhr</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-8"> <p class="bio">Bild eins: «unsagbar» 
    aus dem Zyklus «Ahnengalerie»
    Raffaello hat sie geküsst
    Leonardo war beim Vesper 
    zugegen. Hinter dem Vorhang kommt sie auf eine neue Idee.
    Sie könnte als Skulptur leben. 
    In meiner Malerei geht es um 
    Formen von Lebenserfahrungen.
    Um die Sehnsucht, das Unsagbare darstellen zu können. Und um die Unerträglichkeit, dafür niemals erlösende Bilder zu finden. 
    Was geschieht - ich lasse mich ins Unterbewusstsein fallen und finde Fragmente.
    Künstlerin: Simona Deflorin.</p></div> 

            </div>
            </div>




    </div>
     </div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: nope :/ i mean it works on smartphone but then i have problems on tablets

Comment: Have you tried with the code I sent, Its working well on mobile and we as tablets. please let me know if its not working.

Comment: That's great! Awesome :)